# jLabel MouseEvent, Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mouseevent, jlabel, mouselistener

I want to make button with hover using jLabel. When I come over button errors appears.
I'm using netbeans. Most of the codes generated automatically.

```
public class anaEkrn extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public anaEkrn() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/market2/images/tumu.png"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
    jLabel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel1MouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel1MousePressed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(298, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(23, 23, 23))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(328, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/tumu.png"));
    jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
}                                    

private void jLabel1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    ImageIcon II = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/tumu_hover.png"));
    jLabel1.setIcon(II);
}                                    

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(anaEkrn.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(anaEkrn.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(anaEkrn.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(anaEkrn.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new anaEkrn().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

There are so many errors under this error title.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

What should I do?

Comment: `There are so many errors under this error title.` - and one of them will tell you the line of code in your program that is causing the problem. So get the line number, look at that line, figure out which variable is null and then fix the problem. I would guess the problem is that an image is not found. Why are your images in different directories?

Comment: Error is like 100 lines. Icon that I set works fine, errors appears when I move my mouse over.

Comment: `Error is like 100 lines.` - so you learn to know how to read the information given to you. The line causing the problem in your program will be near the top of the error lines. `errors appears when I move my mouse over.` - and again I ask, why are your images in different directories? You have one icon that works and another that doesn't. What is the difference in your code?

Comment: They are in the same directory. I only write mouseentered and mousepressed codes, others generated automaticly. I noticed when you say program auto added upper folder on url. I write it like css so sorry. Solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `I noticed when you say program auto added upper folder on url.` - that was my point, your code was pointed to different directories.